# split a string only on spaces that are outside curly braces

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex and I need some help. I read some topics similar to this issue, but I could not figure out how to resolve it.

I need to split a string on every blank space that is not inside a pair of curly braces. Consecutive blank spaces outside the curly braces shall be considered as a single one:

```
{ TEST test } test { test test} {test test  }   { 123 } test  test
```

result:

```
{ TEST test } 

test 

{ test test} 

{test test  }   

{ 123 } 

test  

test
```

Comment: What language are you working in?

Comment: I am using MS Visual Studio C#.

Answer (score 3):

```
\{[^}]+\}|\S+
```

This matches either a run of any characters enclosed by curly braces, or a run of non-space characters. Grabbing all of the matches for it out of your string should provide you with what you want.

Comment: I was planning to do something like: string[] test = Regex.Split(line, @"\{[^}]+\}|\S+"); but this way I get a vector only with nulls.

Comment: This regex isn't designed to be used with `Split` - it's designed to be used with [`Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here is exactly what you want...

```
string Source = "{ TEST test } test { test test} {test test } { 123 } test test";
List<string> Result = new List<string>();
StringBuilder Temp = new StringBuilder();
bool inBracket = false;
foreach (char c in Source)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case (char)32:       //Space
            if (!inBracket)
            {
                Result.Add(Temp.ToString());
                Temp = new StringBuilder();
            }
            break;
        case (char)123:     //{
            inBracket = true;
            break;
        case (char)125:      //}
            inBracket = false;
            break;
    }
    Temp.Append(c);
}
if (Temp.Length > 0) Result.Add(Temp.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using:

```
StringCollection information = new StringCollection();  
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(string, @"\{[^}]+\}|\S+"))  
{  
   information.Add(match.Value);  
}
```

Thanks for your help guys !!!