# Splitting a regex based on spaces but inside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem Faced:**

I would like to split a string based on spaces groups, but not if they are inside brackets.

Example :
`"abc    {    def ghi     Klm}    opqr"`
should give me
`["abc", "{    def ghi     Klm}", "opqr"]`

**Solution Needed:**

What is the most readable and most efficient regex in order to do this ?

I know that splitting around spaces can be done like this :

```
sentence.split(/s+/)
```

But I don't know how to go further.

**Duplicate Resolution**

This question was indeed already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165757/662618) (though was in C#). Apologizing

Comment: When giving negative votes, could you also point me to the resources I've missed ? Or to a duplicate question I've missed ?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I think the downvote is because you haven't shown any attempts in actual code. Refer on how to make a [mcve]

Comment: Asking what is most efficient without providing any solutions yourself just makes it sound like you are asking others to do this for you . Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service

Comment: I know how to split around spaces, but this case is too complex for me to resolve, and I haven't found suitable explanation on the web. I've changed my post in order to show what I  already know.

Comment: Can't you break out the brackets first and trim the other character groups?

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate. If related topics didn't help please edit your question to reflect differences.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at them and eventually if needed, will adapt my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regex there is a kind of "dualism", that the same task
can be achieved using either splitting on a pattern or
matching on its "negation".

In your case, due to some limitations of Javascript flavour of regex,
the *matching variant* is better. Use: `/{[^}]*}|\S+/g` to find
matches in your text.

It containt 2 alternatives:

- `{[^}]*}` - opening bracket, a seuence of chars other than `}`
  and `}`.
- `\S+` - a non-empty sequence of chars other than space / tab / newline.

Example code, tested on rextester.com, where just *print* is used
for test printouts:

```
var txt = 'abc    {    def ghi     Klm}    opqr xxx';
var res = txt.match(/{[^}]*}|\S+/g);
print("Length: " + res.length);
for (var j in res) {
    print(res[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex for matching:

```
/{[^}]*}|\S+/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S7tQVM/1)

This regex uses an alternation to match a string between curly brackets using `{[^}]*}` OR matches 1+ non-whitespace characters using `\S+`.

**Code:**

```js
const regex = /{[^}]*}|\S+/gm;
const str = `abc    {    def ghi     Klm}    opqr`;
let m = str.match(regex);

console.log(m);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution and explanation. Indeed this is clever, efficient, and very understandable. Thanks again. (I'll also have a look at the duplicates pointed to me in order to compare).

Comment: Indeed : this was already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165757/662618